# Using one ViewController for multiple scenes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I want to use the same ViewController for multiple scenes. Now I want to implement slightly different behavior depending on which scene is used. I guess this is possible using the identifier. Like (pseudo-code)

```
if (self.identifier == scene1)
{
    // do this
}
else if (self.identifier == scene2)
{
    // do that
}
```

How can I call the identifier from the ViewController?

EDIT:

I mean this identifier from the Inpector - how can I call it in code?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. One possible approach is to name the Segway Identifier and then check for equal string in the prepareForSegue method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HelpSegue"])
    {
        // do this
    }
    else
    {
        // do that
    }
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct design here would be to use an enumerated value, such as:

```
typedef enum{
    kViewControllerStyle1,
    kViewControllerStyle2,
    kViewControllerStyle3
} ViewControllerStyle;
```

Hook up all of the view elements that need adaptation to this style through interface builder outlets and add a switch-case in your "viewDidLoad" method to make the correct adjustments, relying on the current view controller style (also add a "ViewControllerStyle" property to your view controller class).

Comment: Okay, but where do i get the identifier from? UIViewController doesn't have the identifier property (I've edited my question)

Comment: Don't confuse these two things - What I mean is create your own "type" property, you don't need to use the "identifier".

Comment: Thats clear. But how do I set the ViewControllerStyle to the right value?

Comment: When you instantiate the view controller.